# appengine-rest-server Python 2.7 example

Tags: python, google-app-engine, rest, python-2.7

I download the [appengine-rest-server](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-rest-server) (1.0.6) and try to use this module in my aplication but i get some errors. Have anybody a working example with python 2.7.2 ?

Following my code to initalize the module:

```
rest.Dispatcher.base_url = '/rest'
rest.Dispatcher.add_models({
  "customer": customer.customer,
  "place": customer.place})
application = webapp.WSGIApplication([<Some other Routs> ,
                                  ('/rest/.*', rest.Dispatcher)], debug=True)
```

I get this error:

```
File "\src\rest\__init__.py", line 1551, in initialize
  request.disp_query_params_ = None
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'disp_query_params_'
```

Maybe its my fault ?

Comment: Have you tried it with `python2.6`?

Comment: nfortunately not possible, google provide only python 2.3 and 2.7. The  whole aplication is based on 2.7 and the module is 2.7 valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

modify the following function and it seems to work.

```
  def initialize(self, request, response):
        if request != None and response != None: 
            super(Dispatcher, self).initialize(request, response)
            request.disp_query_params_ = None
            response.disp_cache_resp_ = True
            response.disp_out_type_ = TEXT_CONTENT_TYPE
```

Comment: sorry, the 1.0.6 release was intended to be compatible with 2.7, but apparently it wasn't completely.  the 1.0.7 release should be compatible with python 2.7.